# Adding a Radar Chart, programming on Android

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine

i need to add a radar chart to my app. Now i'm using the 
AChartEngine Library but it doesn't support the radar chart type. Do 
someone know some alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a request on the AChartEngine forum and they will probably write such a feature.